# React Native app isn't refreshing after any changes in ios simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I am building an app fo ios but when I change some code it doesn't reflect in simulator. First I am getting error of "No bundler URL found" and I solved it by following instruction given in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCs2GsWNkoo), and after that hot reloading is stopped.
I can't even open the debugger menu on simulator by CMD+d.

When I reopen the app after "yarn react-native start" I can't see a loading process.

NOTE: I wrote "--dev true" in the command give in the video because I found that "--dev false" is not for developer mode.

Any help will be appreciated.

ENVIRONMENT:
MacOS,
"react-native": "^0.66.3",
Xcode: 12.4